# the "three-point" characterization of holomorphy

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I want to know the source of the following "folkloric" fact about holomorphic functions.
 It seems well described by the phrase:
     The three-point characterization of holomorphy. 
 If F is a self-map of the open unit disk D and for every three points in D there exists
 a holomorphic self-map f of D which agrees with F at each of these three points,then F is 
 holomorphic in D.
 There is an "easy",but clever proof using only Schwarz' Lemma and Montel's compactness
 Theorem.